# Doctrine2 gives me wrong sequence numbers (overflow)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, integer-overflow

I'm using Symfony2 and I have some entities defined with `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")` and `@ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="mysequence_seq")`. My sequences are using very big numbers: they are defined as numeric(22).

The problem I have is that Symfony is fetching this values as integers, and this is wrong because this numbers doesn't fit in a single 32bit value. A normal sequence number can be `103500000000000000003` (`1035` is some kind of table identifier, and the other numbers the sequence. Don't ask me why, we've inherited this database). But Doctrine takes this number as 2147483647 (2^31 - 1) and this breaks the sequence numbers and produces PK errors.

My question is: can I alter the datatype Doctrine uses to read sequence numbers without modifying the core? If not, do you have any idea about how to solve this problem? Keep in mind that I can't alter the database or the sequence number format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem.

First, I've defined a custom id generator:

```
class MyIdGenerator extends AbstractIdGenerator
{
    public function generate(EntityManager $em, $entity)
    {
        $stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare(sprintf('SELECT %s.nextval id FROM DUAL', $entity->getGeneratorName()));
        $stmt->execute();
        $rs = $stmt->fetch();

        return $rs['ID'];
    }
```

}

As you can see, in all my entities I've defined a function `getGeneratorName()` that returns a string with the name of the sequence of the table in the Oracle DB.

Finally, in all the needed entities I've changed the id anotations:

```
@ORM\Entity
@ORM\Id
@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
@ORM\SequenceGenerator(class="Acme\BaseBundle\MyIdGenerator")
```